# Regex pattern check

Tags: java, regex

I have to create a regex check for strings of this type:

```
"TEST_PROCESS_"+${variable}
"TEST_PROCESS_"+${variable}+"_PRODUCT"
"TEST_PROCESS_"+${variable}+"_PRODUCT_NEW"
```

this is my regex check:

```
\"(?:[A-Z]+_{1})+\"\+\$\{[a-z]+}(\+\"_{1}[A-Z_]+\")?
```

this is my code:

```
String test = "\"TEST_PROCESS_\"+${variable}+\"_PRODUCT\""; 
if (Pattern.matches("\"(?:[A-Z]+_{1})+\"\\+\\$\\{[a-z]+}(\\+\"_{1}[A-Z_]+\")?", test))        
System.out.println("valid format");
```

The issue I have is that strings of the following types are matched when they should not:

```
"TEST_PROCESS_"+${variable}+"_PRODUCT_"         the last _ is not ok
"TEST_PROCESS_"+${variable}+"__PRODUCT"        __ should not pass
```

Thank you!

Comment: What if the variable has an _ at the end?

Comment: It should not pass, the second part after ${variabile} is optional

Comment: I'm a bit confused because the variable would be interpolated but your regex looks like it is testing its part of the string?

Comment: Can you show the actual declaration of the String and the test code you're using?

Comment: `String test = "\"TEST_PROCESS_\"+${variable}+\"_PRODUCT\"";
if (Pattern.matches("\"(?:[A-Z]+_{1})+\"\\+\\$\\{[a-z]+}(\\+\"_{1}[A-Z_]+\")?", test)) {
      System.out.println("valid format");`

Comment: please add clarifications to the question (vs. posting comments)

Comment: The `[A-Z_]+` is always going to be a problem. What about using the first term test except have a 0 or more clause instead of 1 or more. Then have a word at the end `(?:[A-Z]+_{1})*[A-Z]+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the part after the `${variable}` you can use the same technique, which you used for the part before it. And you need to anchor your regex at the start and the end of the line:

```
^\"(?:[A-Z]+_)+\"\+\$\{[a-z]+\}(?:\+\"(?:_[A-Z]+)+\")?$
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/KnvfDl/1).

Answer (score 0):

You have to restrict that after every underscore, there must be at least one character.

```
^[A-Z](_[A-Z]|[A-Z])*$
```

And if you want the group for the or not to be capturing, you can use this one

```
^[A-Z](?:_[A-Z]|[A-Z])*$
```

And with the whole String-literal wrapping and concatenation it will become

```java
final private static String PATTERN = """
^"[A-Z](?:_[A-Z]|[A-Z])*_"\+\$\{[a-z]+\}\+"(?:_[A-Z]|[A-Z])*"$
""";
```

Since Java 15 you can use text blocks, which helps with unnecessary quote escaping.